# Wrong WebStorm TypeScript Warning "unresolved variable or type angular"?

Tags: angularjs, variables, typescript, webstorm

I have a problem that WebStorm (latest 9.0.3) shows an error "unresolved variable or type angular" on the angular type in the following typescript file:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts"/>
module app.core {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.core', [
    ]);
}
```

I am absolutely sure that the reference path is correct.

The jquery.d.ts file that is referenced by the angular.d.ts file is also there.

The other thing that might be a clue is that WebStorm also complains about a lot of things in the angular.d.ts and the jquery.d.ts files.

It almost looks like that the WebStorm Typescript interpreter has a bug!?

Using an external typescript compiler (I use grunt-ts and ts-lint) works absolutely fine without warnings or errors.

Please help - I find it really distracting having all these red underlines in my WebStorm projects.

Thank you
Christine

Comment: 2 suggestions. 1) try casting angular `(<ng.IAngularStatic>angular)` 2) look through the settings in WS to add TS references through their settings

Comment: Webstorm needs an update for ts 1.4

Comment: I think WebStorm 9.0.3 is already the latest version. What update do you mean?

Comment: OK, thanks to Brocco. So to get that working I had to install WebStorm 10 EAP.